# Round field values in configure popups in ArcGIS Pro 3.1

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup

Based on the popup `text` below how can I round the fields being used in the text to zero decimal places? Like is there a way to do it in the text box itself without modifying the fields in the attribute table?

```
Average Surface Temperature: {HighAvgSurfaceT_F_} F
Percent Canopy Lacking: {PCT_Lacking}%
Population Density: {POP_SQMI_1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the number of decimal places shown in a pop-up in ArcGIS Pro.

Here is a before scenario, defaults were accepted, we see LENGTHKM is showing 3 decimal places.

[image: Before configure]

Right click on the layer in the TOC and choose configure popups, then hover fields and you will see a tiny pencil, click on that.

[image: Edit fields]

Hover over the field you want to change and you'll see an ellipse button appear, click on that.

[image: Ellipse button]

Set decimal places to zero then press the back arrow button.

[image: Back arrow]

You will now see your data in the correct decimal places when you click on a feature with the explore button.